# Maya Installation: No such file error but the the file Exists - i386 architecture not the issue

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 64-bit

I am trying to install Maya on my linux. It is an original student version from autodesk own webpage.

The installation [guide](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Installation-Maya/files/GUID-10FE31A8-7092-45BE-9E53-44D0D096E431-htm.html) tells me to go to the directory and run `./setup` but when i do that i get the error:

```
./setup: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is weird because the file and directory does in fact exist. I read elsewhere that if the binary is 32 bit then I should build a i386 architecture. But that is not the issue because when i use `file setup` command then it outputs:

```
setup: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Can anyone tell a Linux beginner like me how to solve this?

Comment: Try doing `chmod +x setup` first

Comment: Sorry that didn't change anything. Thx anyways

Comment: The file is a shared library and ~/.setup is probably not on your path. Could be a dependency problem as well.

Comment: Might want to give this a read: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/installing-maya-on-ubuntu/td-p/4905036

Comment: None of that is the issue

Comment: I suspect your system is 32-bit then...

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release (output of `lsb_release -a`) and system architecture (output of `uname -m` and/or `dpkg --print-architecture`)?